# Embed Index in created PDF?

Tags: indexing, acrobat, search

Acrobat Pro offers the functionality to embed a search Index into a PDF. Is there a way to do this via Tex functionalities without the need to buy the official Acrobat Pro license to embed search index INTO an existing PDF?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I mean the Embedded Search Index Feature:
http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1809120&seqNum=2

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "search index" I don't think I've heard that term before in relation to Acrobat

Comment: @daleif: I added in my question in the edit.

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of it and as Adobe does not support Linux, I do not have access to it.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. Embedding a file is easy, but the format of the index file is acrobat specific and unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search index is implemented with a `/PieceInfo` entry in the catalog:

```
/PieceInfo 
<<
/SearchIndex 
<<
/PDXFile 13 0 R
/ModID (215673870f8f9142afe419c9ca1a4620)
/Index1File 14 0 R
/IndexFile 15 0 R
>>
>>
```

The index files it points to are binary streams.

The description of the `/PieceInfo` dictionary in the pdf reference says:

> PDF writers can use this dictionary as a place to store private data
>   in connection with that document, page, or form. Such private data can
>   convey information meaningful to the PDF processor that produces it
>   [...] but can be ignored by general-purpose PDF processors.

This means that the content and the format of this index is acrobat specific. To be able to create such an index with tex you would need to know the specification, which probably isn't public.

Even if the specification were known I doubt that it would make sense to include this in the tex compilation - it would slow down it a lot. It would make more sense to postprocess only the final pdf.